# how to have different stroke and fill colors for a shape in Java Graphics2D?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a rounded rectangle with a colored stroke. Below is the code I have so far:

```
        float thickness = textbox.getStroke();
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));
        
        g2d.setColor(colorsList[textbox.getStrokeColor()]);
        g2d.drawRoundRect(x, y, xSize, ySize, round, round);
        g2d.setColor(colorsList[textbox.getColor()]); // set box color
        g2d.fillRoundRect(x, y, xSize, ySize, round, round);
        
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0));
```

[image: This]

This is the stroke that comes out of the above code. It draws a rounded rectangle with the stroke and then the smaller fill inside, imitating having a stroke (in fact, this can be done without strokes at all and just using a slightly larger rounded rect). However, since the precision of the graphics 2D goes up to int, it's quite clear that the top of the stroke is slightly smaller than the bottom, and it's more so the smaller the stroke is.

Instead, I want to use something like g2d.setStrokeColor() (this does not exist, as far as I  know) which can allow me to simply drawRoundRect() and not have to worry about filling the center fill with another roundedRect to get a different color.

Comment: You appear to be doing it the (a) right way: `draw`ing and then `fill`ing the same shape with different colors.  You could also consider doing it in the opposite order, which I expect to emphasize the stroke more.  Caveats include that yes, if you use shape dimensions or stroke thicknesses that are not integers then you will be subject to FP rounding.  Perhaps you could mitigate that by [requesting higher quality rendering by setting rendering hints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html), but ultimately, your output device is pixelated, not continuous.

Comment: [Graphics2D docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rendering-compatibility-issues-heading): “The JDK 1.1 rendering model is based on a pixelization model that specifies that coordinates are infinitely thin, lying between the pixels. Drawing operations are performed using a one-pixel wide pen that fills the pixel below and to the right of the anchor point on the path.” And later: “Java 2D API maintains compatibility with JDK 1.1 rendering behavior, such that legacy operations and existing renderer behavior is unchanged under Java 2D API.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I misunderstood what the .drawRoundRect method does, and assumed it also drew the fill. It does not. By drawing the fill first and then drawing the stroke, the problem with the stroke seeming to be shorter on one side is solved.